# Read file when process is down

Tags: bash, shell, unix

createFile is a binary which create a file tmp_file.csv
whenever I will run createFile, 0 byte tmp_file.csv is  created and when the binary is completed, data is written into tmp_file.csv file

I have to check when createFile is complete then use tmp_file.csv file.
Below is what I am doing :

```
while true
do
pid=$(psu | grep createFile | grep -v grep | wc -l  )
if [[ $pid -eq 0 ]]
then
    break
fi  
done
```

After loop is broken, I read tmp_file.csv file.

Is there any better way which can be done without using loop.

Comment: Does tmp_file.csv exist before the process is started? If not ,you could use test -e on the file path.

Comment: If the criterion is a non-zero sized tmp_file.csv, then a much better idea (less useless forks and pipes) is: `while ! test -s tmp_file.csv; do sleep 1; done`.

Comment: BTW, did you mean "Read file when process is DONE" instead of "DOWN"?

Comment: @Jens : Process will write to file and then go DOWN

Comment: Your code will eat up all CPU time. Add a `sleep` somewhere.

Comment: @RamanSailopal: No, each time I will run the binary, new file is created

Comment: You can also run find to check for the file also. As @ceving explained, add sleeps and try the different options (test/find) then run the script with "time" and see which one runs the most efficiently.

Comment: What process is running createFile?  That is the best place to make the necessary changes.  The parent of createFile knows when it is finished; take advantage of that information.

Comment: You've got the terminology wrong. Hardware goes down. Processes *exit* (or maybe go to sleep and wait).